# Finding the value of x and y in given two matrices

Tags: matrices

Problem :

Two matrices A$ =\begin{pmatrix}
2& 3\\ 5 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$  and B =$\begin{pmatrix}
1&x&7 \\ 6&-3&-y
\end{pmatrix}$ are equal , then find the value of x +y ?

I know that if the order  the two matrices are same then only we can compare their elements, is it a wrong question and if not please suggest how to proceed for this..? Thanks..

Comment: For two matrices to be equal, the first necessary condition is that they have the same number of rows and columns. End of the problem.

Comment: Might you have copied the question incorrectly? It is impossible for these to be equal since they are of different dimensions.

Comment: Maybe there's some more context that reveals matter of convention how to compare matrices with different dimensionality, but as it is right now I, personally, don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe @Sultan typed it in incorrectly?

Comment: I don't know why people have given negative votes I asked them about rectification of this error and I have typed this question correctly from book, as the answer given in book is x = 0 , y = 0 .....Thanks..

Comment: @sultan , a matter of knowing how to write questions: many of us (yes, I'm the first one!) don't read the whole question but only the main text of it. Had you *first* explained that you have a doubt and etc. people would have, probably, paid attention better to it.